# Order style-sheet list when adding custom one via template_preprocess_page()

Tags: 6, theming

I'm using `phptemplate_preprocess_page()` to add a set of style-sheets which are only needed for a certain content type.

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->type == 'example') {
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/example.css');
    $variables['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
  }
}
```

The problem is that my added style-sheet is added to the top of the list, which results in undesired behavior. For example, let's say that in my main theme style-sheet I define the `font-size` of `p` to be `11px`, but in my `example.css` for this specific content type I need it to be `15px`. The main style-sheet is added via the `.info` file of the theme.

It seems I can only think of icky ways to add my specific style-sheet at the bottom of the list, or at least below the theme default ones.

Is there any proper way to order them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, of course, a few moments after adding the question I saw what was wrong. Since I did not specify the type it added my style-sheets it added it to the end of the modules. I now added the theme type and it was added at the end of the list.